# Keyboard not focusing in overlay EditText. Keyboard is opening as expected but it is not working

Tags: java, android, overlay

[image]

when I type anything on keyboard then google opening. Not able to type in this EditText view.
Here I have created overlay services. and here I have written the codes for force open soft Keyboard logic.
floatingPointWidthService.java

```
 public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //init WindowManager
        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        getWindowManagerDefaultDisplay();
        //Init LayoutInflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        addRemoveView(inflater);
        addFloatingWidgetView(inflater);
        implementClickListeners();
        implementTouchListenerToFloatingWidgetView();
        System.out.println("mFloatingWidgetView" +mFloatingWidgetView);
        expandedView = mFloatingWidgetView.findViewById(R.id.expanded_container);
        expandedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//set large view open
        edittext1 = mFloatingWidgetView.findViewById(R.id.floating_widget_title_label);
        edittext1.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(edittext1.getApplicationWindowToken(), 1);
        imm.showSoftInput(edittext1, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    }
```

Here I have changes `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ModFill"
        tools:targetApi="31"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"// this is for overlayKeyBoard
>
```

This is layout of overlay modal here I have added the EditText.
floating_width_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!--   Root container of Floating Widget View  -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--  View while view is collapsed  -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <!--   ImageView of floating widget  -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/collapsed_iv"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <!--   Close button to close Floating Widget View  -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/close_floating_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!--   View while view is expanded   -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/expanded_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/floating_widget_image_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/floating_widget_title_label"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Enter your comment"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!--  ImageView to Close Expanded View  -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/close_expanded_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp" />

            <!--  ImageView to Open Activity  -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/open_activity_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_aspect_ratio_black_24dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

keyboard is opening with last line `imm.toggleSoftInput` method. Please tell how to type text in this EditText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(edittext1.getApplicationWindowToken(), 1);
    imm.showSoftInput(edittext1, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

You don't need any of that.  Setting the focus is sufficient.  And in particular the 2nd and 4th lines here are wrong-  both of them will show the keyboard, but not hook it up properly to the InputConnection and thus lead to a keyboard that appears but does nothing.

Comment: I have removed 2nd and 4th line then keyboard is not opening. ```imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);``` this line is responsible here to open keyboard.

Comment: Yes, it opens the keyboard without properly connecting it to anything.  You don't need to do anything to open the keyboard normally-  focusing an element is generally sufficient, unless you did something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Overlaying an EditText widget on top of another app and automatically opening the keyboard is not supported in the standard Android framework. The security measures prevent apps from programmatically controlling the keyboard behavior in other apps for security and privacy reasons. --reply from chatGpt

Comment: @ProkashDev you fixed it? I'm facing the same problem, the keyboard shows, but the letters doesnt appears in the ediTtext, could you share the code if you fixed it?